# why we can't assign a string value to 2d char array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char a[3][5];
int i;

a[0][5]="hai";
a[1][5]="cool";
a[2][5]="many";

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
printf("%s \n",a[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Why we cant assign string value like this but it can be assigned using string function?

Comment: The string chapter of your C programming book would have mentioned `strcpy`pretty early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option for read only access (if you don't modify the string literal) is an array of pointers:

```
char *a[3]; /* Or better yet: const char *a[3]; */

a[0]="hai";
a[1]="cool";
a[2]="many";
```

Comment: okay this looks something new, here a[3] is a 1d char array right but you have declared it as pointer. During normal declaration of 1d array, it can be said as 'a' is a char array of size 3.                                                     but here it looks like a 1d array but performs like a 2d array how internally the array name is stored.

Comment: Yes, it is a 1D array of pointers, it looks like a 2D array because `a[0]` is a pointer to a string literal, in other words: you can use array subscript `int c = (a[0][0] == 'h') ? 1 : 0;` but is still a 1D array of (unmodifiable) `char *`s (used with string literals). Used with (non literals) arrays of  `char`s, the contents of those pointers are also modifiable, an [example](https://ideone.com/pA1O1z))

Answer (score 4):

You have three problems. The first is that you attempt to assign a pointer to a single `char`. The second problem is that the single character you try to assign to is out of bounds.

The third problem is that you can not assign to an array, only copy to it.

You can solve all three problems by *copying* the string into the array, using the [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function:

```
strcpy(a[0], "hai");
```

Be careful not to copy a string that is to long to fit in the destination array though, as that will then write out of bounds and lead to undefined behavior. The source can not be longer than four characters (five with the terminator). The can be solved by using [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) instead, but that function have another problem that can leave the destination string unterminated instead.

---

To clarify: In the assignment `a[0][5] = "hai"` the expression `a[0][5]` is  single character, but it is also [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since index `5` is out of bounds.

Then the string literal is actually an array of four characters (the characters `'h'`, `'a'`, `'i'` and the string terminator `'\0'`). When using the string literal in an expression like your assignment, it *decays* to a pointer to its first element. Therefore `"hai"` could be seen as a pointer.

So in `a[0][5] = "hai"` you assign a *pointer* to the letter `'h'` in the string, to the single and out of bounds character `a[0][5]`.

Comment: since i am a beginner i  didn't get you, in my code which is a pointer and the single char as of you said

Comment: @SathishM Updated my answer with some clarifications.

Comment: Upvoted. This is, in my opinion, superior to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should check the datatypes for the operands of the assignment operators.

On the LHS, you have a `char`, and you're trying to assign a `char *` (RHS) to it. This is type mismatch, hence not possible.

That said, `a` being a two-dimensional array, you cannot even *assign* to `a[0]` either, as arrays (*not array elements*) are not assignable.

You have to copy the string literal *into* the memory, however, you have to do something like

```
 strcpy(a[0], "hai");
```

So, to answer,

> *....but it can be assigned using string function?*

Well, there's a difference between assignment using assignment operator and copying using the string-family library function. They don't behave the same way. Assignment using assignment operator to an array is not possible, as it needs a modifiable lvalue as the left operand, and an array (name) is not a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: okay understood, string assignment can be done only by copying the string into the array.

Answer (score 0):

The *type* of `"hai"` is a `const char[4]`. Although in certain instances it does *decay* to a `const char*`.

You are attempting to assign a `const char[4]` type to a `char` type. That's a *type mismatch* and the compiler will disallow that.

You could, however, write `strncpy(a[0], "hai", 5);` where 5 is the upper limit of the number of characters that can be copied from the string literal.